# Native Substrate runtime support for storing data Offchain to IPFS

Tags: storage, offchain-storage

There appear to be 2 two substrate forks addressing offchain data storage with a IPFS backend:

- https://github.com/iridium-labs/substrate/tree/iris
- https://github.com/WunderbarNetwork/substrate/tree/ipfs-ocw

As best I can tell (very new here so could be wrong) they take 2 different approaches: Pallet vs chain extension.

1. What are the relative merits of each approach to implementing IPFS: pallet vs extension chain?
2. Which is more likely to land upstream?
3. Is it possible to track/estimate the time frame in which these might land upstream?

This is not the question: what are the ways to store offchain data

Comment: The implementation on how to store offchain data is maintainer's responsibility. These solutions will not land into core substrate repo.

Comment: Offchain data can be stored in offchain storage. Those forks are custom implementation. 
I think the question could be more clear if you asked what are the ways to store offchain data and i believe there are answers already

Comment: `> These solutions will not land into core substrate repo.`

New here... are you a member of the core team?

Comment: am a contributor but these are personal custom implementation. the core team implementation is to use offchain db which is already configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a pallet
2. It is unclear. See my comment [here](https://github.com/w3f/Grants-Program/pull/1187#issuecomment-1283354955) for more detail behind this summary:

   - Upstream changes to Substrate are required for native Substrate runtime support of IPFS (things have been tried).
   - [Upstream is not resistant](https://github.com/rs-ipfs/offchain-ipfs-manual/issues/22#issuecomment-877354507)
   - Upstream changes won't be easy/quick
   - Web3 Foundation have made two grants related/using IPFS, but not focused on getting IPFS in the native Substrate runtime
   - The Iris grant project completed
   - The offchain_ipfs project review/merge of contributions stalled due to lack of resources
   - Substrate forks proliferate....
3. No

**Update:**
rs-ipfs is in a state of flux, possibly being [archived](https://github.com/rs-ipfs/rust-ipfs/pull/512), with [iroh](https://github.com/n0-computer/iroh) being a new candidate. Performance is [impressive (presentation)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPBR2K2X6cs&t=161s) but it is early days.

Substrate forking seems unavoidable for the foreseeable future, say 12+ months

Answer (score 0):

The "native" approach uses the off-chain worker(ocw) functionality to interact with IPFS. I'd guess a Substrate pallet for IPFS doesn't exist because each implementation will have its differences and require somewhat of a custom implementation. I think the projects you've linked and discussed are the ones to watch. Maybe search some big parachain projects to see if they have any IPFS ocws.